# Redis Python modules installed by default

Tags: python, redis

Is there a way to determine which Redis Python modules are installed by default? I do not have a Redis installation, but would like to know for planning purposes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

None of the Redis client modules are part of the Python standard library.

To work with Redis, you will need to install a client module, I recommend redis-py, using your preferred package manager.

Comment: Thank you Tague . Do you know where something about which libraries are installed by default is written or is the best way to just install Redis?

Comment: Take a look at the Redis documentation on StackOverflow for the section on working with Python, it should get you started. (https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/redis/9103/connecting-to-redis-using-python#t=201707172214509908715).  The Python tutorial (https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) should give you information on what libraries are included in the standard library.

Comment: Tague, I have installed Redis. Do you happen to know if there is a command I can run to see which libraries are installed on the server?